# Finding the x coordinate of a point in the solution of NDSolve from its y coordinate

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Using `NDSolveValue`, we can know the y coordinate of the function from an x coordinate.  Is it possible to do the reverse, where the input is the y coordinate and the program will output the corresponding x coordinate?

Thank you.

Comment: If you know the solution is monotone, you can use `InverseFunction[y]` in the second argument of `NDSolveValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there may be multiple values of `x` for a given value of `y`. For example,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ysol = NDSolveValue[
  {y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
```

Let the value of `y` of interest be `0.2`

```
Plot[{ysol[x], 0.2}, {x, 0, 30},
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.45},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Since the inverse is multi-valued, an estimate for `x` must be provided to indicate which solution should be found.

```
xval[y_?NumericQ, xEst_?NumericQ] := 
  FindRoot[ysol[x] == y, {x, xEst}]
```

To find all solutions,

```
xsol = x /. (xval[0.2, #] & /@ {3, 7, 9, 13, 15})

(* {3.03258, 6.20767, 8.80558, 13.1243, 14.6631} *)
```

Verifying that these values of `x` give the target value

```
And @@ (ysol[#] == 0.2 & /@ xsol)

(* True *)
```